# Найти номер строки с максимальной суммой квадратов в двумерном массиве

Tags: python, массивы

Подскажите как можно найти в двумерном массиве номер строки, которая должна быть самой большой по длине?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какое отношение рисунок с синусом имеет к тексту вопроса о самой длинной строке?

Comment: @jfs, похоже это формула заполнения матрицы

Answer (score 2):

*Вопрос*:

> Подскажите как можно найти в двумерном массиве номер строки, которая должна быть самой большой по длине?

*Ответ*:

```
arr = [['some', 'cut', 'dog'], ['room', 'red', 'green'], ['abdc', 's', 'mem']]

strMax = '' ## Longest string
pos_j = 0
pos_i = 0
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    for j in range(0, len(arr[i])):
        if len(arr[i][j]) > len(strMax):
            strMax = arr[i][j]
            pos_i = i
            pos_j = j


print (strMax, i, j)
```

Comment: `longest_string = max((s for row in array2D for s in row), key=len)`

Comment: @jfs даже не сомневался, что есть однострочный эквивалент поиску самой длинной строки в 2Д массиве :)

Comment: @KostaB., прошу прощения, похоже моя правка вопроса, сделала ваш ответ некорректным. Я могу вернуть предыдущий вариант, хотя, судя по картинке, речь идет о числовых элементах, полученных при помощи формулы из левой части (с синусом)

Comment: @MaxU если, ваша правка это истинная суть вопроса, то я удалю свой ответ. Хотелось бы услышать вопрошающего по этому поводу.

Comment: @KostaB., лучше вместо удаления добавить в начало ответа задачу (вопрос) в том виде как вы ее поняли и ответили на нее... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Решение с ипользованием модуля *Numpy*:

```
import numpy as np

# заполнение 2D матрицы    
nx,ny = 5,4
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1, nx+1), np.arange(1, ny+1), indexing='ij')
a = np.sqrt(xv + yv) * np.sin(xv)
print(a)

# решение
row_idx = (a**2).sum(axis=1).argmax()
# индексирование в Python (и в Numpy) начинается с 0
print(f'Номер строки с максимальной длиной: {row_idx+1}')
```

Вывод:

```
[[ 1.19001968  1.4574705   1.68294197  1.88158632]
 [ 1.57494934  1.81859485  2.03325086  2.22731472]
 [ 0.28224002  0.31555393  0.34567201  0.37336845]
 [-1.69226183 -1.85377995 -2.00231119 -2.14056071]
 [-2.34887517 -2.53707516 -2.71224743 -2.87677282]]

Номер строки с максимальной длиной: 5
```

Матрица "длин" строк:

```
In [48]: np.sqrt((a**2).sum(axis=1))
Out[48]: array([3.14849613, 3.85782226, 0.66191151, 3.85895069, 5.25224456])
```

PS Для нахождения *индекса максимума*, извлечение корня это лишняя операция, т.к. не влияет на результат.